# Carrierwave error: version doesn't exist! in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I´m using Carrierwave (2.0.2, 0.11.2) in Rails 5.2.3. and I´m pretty stuck with versions of uploaded images.
 Imagemagick is latest version,gems Carrierwave,Rmagick and Minimagick installed.
Everything works as it should with two versions created by default and uncommented in uploaders/image_uploader.rb file:
just like this:

```
version :large do
  process resize_to_fill: [500,500]
end

version :thumb from :large do
  process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
end

version :long do
  process resize_to_fill: [500,200]
end
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Slide < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  before_save :update_image_attributes
  after_save :recreate_delayed_versions!

  validates :image_title, presence: true
  validates :display, presence: true
  validates :order, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :image
  validates_integrity_of :image
  validates_processing_of :image

  def recreate_delayed_versions!
     image.recreate_versions!(:thumb,:large,:long)
  end

  private

  def update_image_attributes
    if image.present? && image_changed?
      self.image_content_type = image.file.content_type
      self.image_file_size = image.file.size
    end
  end
end
```

Uploaded images are processed,scaled and saved in :original size,:large and :thumb version in correct folders...all good.
But if I try to create another version,or rename existing one,for example " version :long ",it doesn´t create it and in my views exception is caught as: "Version long doesn't exist!"
I did tried several different version names,amount of versions,name as symbol,in quotation marks,also reading the source code of Carrierwave/versions.rb,reading documentation,but still unable to find any reason for this behaviour.Only those two versions working well,not any other.Could You someone help me with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rename the version or adding new version, you are required to recreate those versions by calling something like this:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user.avatar.recreate_versions!
end
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions)

Comment: Hi,thank You for reply.I edited my question with method defined in my model..is that correct?

Comment: No, it's one time script to run. Like after every time you rename a version or adding new version, you just have to run this script once in  `rails console`.

Comment: What is your model look like?

Comment: Now I tried that in rails console and suddenly it works.Don´t understand,why my method called after_save doesn´t recreate those versions??Anyway,you solved my issue!Thank you very much!